# Handling a bad API request from user

Tags: python, rest, flask

I am trying to display a custom error message when the user enters the wrong time zone in the url.
In this case the user is suppose to enter EST to fetch this specific time zone but if he enters a timezone that does not exist I want to handle that error. How do I do this?
Here is my code:

```
'''
http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_time?time_zone=est eastern
http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_time?time_zone=pst for pacific etc
http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_time?time_zone=mdt wrong time zone 
returns:
TypeError
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
'''


import requests
import json
import jsonpath
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask import jsonify


app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")

@app.route('/get_time', methods=['GET'])
def get_timec():
    time_zone = request.args.get('time_zone')
    url = "http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/" + time_zone + "/now"



    response = requests.get(url)

    json_response = json.loads(response.text)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        print("Error on response")
        return response.status_code


    print("Here is your time in the East Coast of the US: ")
    return json_response['currentDateTime']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Are you asking "How do I validate time_zone?" or "How should I respond to the client if they provide an invalid time zone?" Not sure specifically what you are asking for help with

Comment: How do I respond to the client if they provide an invalid time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would return a [status code of 400](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) and other information in the response that can help the caller understand why their request was rejected. The simplest way to do this with flask is by returning a `flask.Response` like so:

```
@app.route('/get_time', methods=['GET'])
def get_timec():
    time_zone = request.args.get('time_zone')
    if not is_valid_time_zone(time_zone):
        return flask.Response(
            status=400, content_type='application/json', response=json.dumps({
                'reason': 'Invalid timezone: "{}"'.format(time_zone),
                'code': 1  # Many APIs implement a more specific code system to help callers debug things like this.
            }))

    # Continue handling the request...
```

If you would prefer to use exceptions, Flask provides ways to customize how raised exceptions are propagated to the caller. You can read more about this [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/apierrors/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```
try:
    time_zone = request.args.get('time_zone')
    url = "http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/" + time_zone + "/now"
    r = requests.get(url)
except Exception:
    return make_response(jsonify({"Error": "Some error message"}), 400)
return jsonify({"Success": r.json()})
```

Pick the right [status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) according to what error the user might be causing...

You'll also need  `from flask import jsonify, make_response`

The 400 could be any other code... maybe they sent some missing form fields or didn't include a JSON body in a POST request... Maybe they didn't put the right username and password and need a 401 Unauthorized etc.

As a side note, the return success message doesn't use make_response because it will return a 200-ok by default if I remember correctly.

Also if you are returning JSON to the user, `r.json()` may be a better option than `r.text`.